# Как вывод записи из БД присвоить переменной

Tags: php, html, mysql

У меня есть php-код и база данных. Из таблицы `kurs` мне надо взять одно значение. И это значение надо умножить к переменным. Я смог вытащить ту ячейку, которая мне нужна. Но не смог выполнить нужную арифметическую операцию.

```
<?php
            $sdd_db_host='localhost'; 
            $sdd_db_name='mybase'; 
            $sdd_db_user='admin'; 
            $sdd_db_pass='qwerty'; 
            @mysql_connect($sdd_db_host,$sdd_db_user,$sdd_db_pass); 
            @mysql_select_db($sdd_db_name); 
            $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kurs where id=1");
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            echo '<td width="85"><div   align="center">'.$row[Продажа].'</div></td>';      
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 { 
    $var = $row[Продажа];
    //  Делайте с $var нужную арифметическую операцию
    echo '<td width="85"><div   align="center">'.$var.'</div></td>';      
 }
```